# Swipe Gesture calling the method multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a small problem that em stuck on.. i have a Custom `UITableViewCell`, on its `textView` i have added **2 gestures**, `UITapGesture` and `UISwipeGesture`.. the *tap gesture* is working fine but the *swipe gesture* is **calling the method multiple times**.. some times calling it twice and some times even more than that… Here's how i have added them to the cell

```
//added in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapToTranslate = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapToTranslate:)];
[tapToTranslate setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapToTranslate setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
tapToTranslate.delegate = self;
[cell.messageContentView addGestureRecognizer:tapToTranslate];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeToTranslate = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(translateTo:)];
swipeToTranslate.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeToTranslate.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeToTranslate.delegate = self;
[cell.messageContentView addGestureRecognizer: swipeToTranslate];
```

These are there methods…

```
-(void)tapToTranslate:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)aGesture {}

-(void)translateTo:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)aGesture 
{
    aGesture.enabled = false;
}
```

I've tried to disable Swipe Gesture in its method after its called but that didn't help..

I've also have the `uigesturerecognizer` delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

So Any help would be great…
thanks in advance…

**EDIT 1**

```
<UITextView: 0x11322f700; frame = (18 10; 160.865 69.2656); text = '你怎么样？    How are you doing?'; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x11322fbd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x11322fac0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole code in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method ? Try to add log in `-(void)translateTo:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)aGesture`, `NSLog(@"%@", aGesture.view) ;` Let's see if it is the same view.

Comment: ok em trying this NSLog..

Comment: edited the question with what i got

Comment: Does it show the same UITextView: 0x11322f700 all the time ?

Comment: Yes… Suddenly just by removing the `delegate=self;` has got it working ….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Removing the `gesture.delegate = self;` line from both the gestures, the method started calling once as it was suppose to do. Apparently doing the job for me. So for anyone facing this issue, they can try removing the `gesture's delegate` and its method.

Answer (score 2):

The `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` does call the function multiple times for different states like  `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, and several other states. It also keeps on calling the function constantly while it is swiping which can be handled in the last else statement below. In the swipe gesture function, do this:

```
-(void)translateTo:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)aGesture
{
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
//do something
} 
else if(recognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
}
else
{
 //do something while it is swiping
}
}
```

The below answer may not be in correspondence to what you intend to do but still might help you: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226239/uiswipegesturerecognizer-called-twice)

Comment: its always calling UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.. never going in Began or else...

Comment: swipe is a discrete gesture

Comment: "swipe is a discrete gesture" means?

Comment: @AhmedZ. There are two types of gesture, one is discrete, the other is continuous. Discrete gesture don't have begin state.

Comment: oh, thanks for sharing that… :) do u know why me method is called multiple times?

Comment: @KudoCC Discrete gestures do not mean that they don't have a began state. Swipe gestures does have a began state and it gets called.

Comment: Discrete has three states, possible, fail, or recognized. Check it in the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW17)

Comment: @KhawarAli Because "**Swipe** is a **discrete gesture**"

Comment: @AhmedZ. I also said that it is a discrete gesture, but being discrete does not mean that the began state does not get called. It just means that the functions is not called repeatedly. The began state does get called in the swipe gesture!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, Tableview is having its own gesture recognizers. By adding additional gestures over the tableview it is somehow confusing with the gesture to call. This might be the reason of this issue. Here is the solution;

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    if ([gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
}
```

You can recognize simultaneous gestures using this.

Comment: Yes I think that could be the issue… do u know how u could solve it?

Comment: Please check the solution, and it became an answer now:)

Comment: I tried this.. added `return NO;` for gestures of `UITableView class` and `YES` for the other one but still doing the same thing...

Comment: Your requirement is only to swipe left?